# how can i use scrapy to extract two level text?

Tags: python, scrapy

My code is not working properly.

The second for loop is not getting all text.

How can I do that in scrapy?

Thanks for any tips and let me know if I'm missing anything.

```
<dl>
<dt>Release Date:</dt>
<dd>Aug. 01, 2016<br>
</dd>

<dt>Runtime:</dt>
<dd itemprop="duration">200min.<br></dd>

<dt>Languages:</dt>
<dd>Japanese<br></dd>
<dt>Subtitles:</dt>
<dd>----<br></dd>
<dt>Content ID:</dt>
<dd>8dtkm00045<br></dd>
<dt>Actress(es):</dt>
<dd itemprop="actors">
    <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <a itemprop="name">Shinobu Oshima</a>
    </span>

    <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <a itemprop="name">Yukie Mizukami</a>
    </span>

</dd>
```

SPIDER :

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="contents"]/div[10]/section/section[1]/section[1]'):
        item = EnMovie()
        Content_ID = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl/dt[contains (.,"Content ID:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text())').extract()
        item['Content_ID'] = Content_ID[0].encode('utf-8')
        release_date = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl[1]/dt[contains (.,"Release Date:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text())').extract()
        item['release_date'] = release_date[0].encode('utf-8')
        running_time = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl[1]/dt[contains (.,"Runtime:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text())').extract()
        item['running_time'] = running_time[0].encode('utf-8')
        Series = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl[2]/dt[contains (.,"Series:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text())').extract()
        item['Series'] = Series[0].encode('utf-8')
        Studio = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl[2]/dt[contains (.,"Studio:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/a/text())').extract()
        item['Studio'] = Studio[0].encode('utf-8')
        Director = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl[2]/dt[contains (.,"Director:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text())').extract()
        item['Director'] = Director[0].encode('utf-8')
        Label = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl[2]/dt[contains (.,"Label:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text())').extract()
        item['Label'] = Label[0].encode('utf-8')
        item['image_urls'] = sel.xpath('div[1]/img/@src').extract()


        for actress in sel.xpath("//*[@itemprop='actors']//*[@itemprop='name']"):
            actress_ = actress.xpath("text()").extract()
           item['Actress'] = actress_[0].strip()
           yield item
```

Partially spider works well.(Except for the second for loop) Second for loop yield only the last [itemprop="name"] value and saved to DB.

Sorry for my bad English and Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Is the extra space at the front of the first line in the second `for` loop the problem?

Comment: So, do you need one separated EnMovie item for each actress? Or do you need a list with all the actresses from the movie inside the item?

Comment: I need one separated EnMovie item for each actress!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your second loop with this:

```
actresses = sel.xpath("//*[@itemprop='actors']//*[@itemprop='name']/text()").extract()

item['Actress'] = [x.strip() for x in actresses]

yield item
```

It will give an item which has a list of actresses.

BYW, please stop posting the same question [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520312/why-does-my-scrapy-not-scrape-anything) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565891/why-does-my-scrapy-not-scrape-anything) and again.